# How can I force Javascript to sync Date.now() to the system clock

Tags: javascript, system-clock

I have a Javascript application running on a server that is referencing `Date.now()` from a Worker thread.

When the system clock on the machine changes I have a (non-JS) application that notices this and accounts for the change.

But the Javascript app takes a long time (circa seconds) before `Date.now()` starts reporting the changed system clock.

How can I force the `Date.now()` to reset itself when the app becomes aware of the system clock change?

Comment: `the Javascript app` - so, not a browser?

Comment: Actually the JS app is running in a browser on that machine.

Comment: then the issue is with the browser being slow to react to time changes - absolutely nothing your web page can do about that (not sure what a `JS App in browser` is

Comment: Its an Angular app running in the browser. The app knows that the SysClock has changed because it has received notification from another app. Is there anyway to tell the browser or JS container to reload/resync the system clock?

Comment: No, a web page can't tell the browser to resync the time - which browser is it? Firefox reacts immediately to the system clock changing time

Comment: note: `Angular App` is still just a web page

Comment: Chrome 101.0.4951.54

Comment: What OS. it may be an OS thing rather than a browser thing ... but knowing how Chrome is .... anyway, can you check if this reaction to system clock change is as retarded in Firefox. Also check any other browser you have - see if it's browser related - if you find it's just Chrome (and chrome base browsers like Edge for example) then I'll add this to my list of "reasons to never use Chrome again" list - it's a BIG list